# Can't install AnyDesk on Linux Mint 20 as libminizip1 and libgtkglext1 dependencies goes wrong

Tags: linux, linux-mint, anydesk

Despite a straightforward installation of AnyDesk on a previous version of Linux Mint, here on Linux Mint 20, it seems there is no way at all to install AnyDesk.

Particularly, there are a couple of dependencies, one of them being libgtkglext1, and the other libminizip1, which can not be satisfied.

Here I report the anwer on the console, which is in Italian, hopefully that wouldn't be a problem

```
(Lettura del database... 320926 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre anydesk_6.1.1-1_amd64.deb...
Failed to stop anydesk.service: Unit anydesk.service not loaded.
Estrazione di anydesk (6.1.1) su (6.1.1)...
dpkg: problemi con le dipendenze impediscono la configurazione di 
anydesk:
anydesk dipende da libminizip1; tuttavia:
Il pacchetto libminizip1 non è installato.
anydesk dipende da libgtkglext1; tuttavia:
Il pacchetto libgtkglext1 non è installato.

dpkg: errore nell'elaborare il pacchetto anydesk (--install):
problemi con le dipendenze - lasciato non configurato
Elaborazione dei trigger per hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per desktop-file-utils 
(0.24+linuxmint1)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per mime-support (3.64ubuntu1)...
Si sono verificati degli errori nell'elaborazione:
anydesk


root@passerotta-X55VDR:~# apt policy  libminizip1 libgtkglext1

libminizip1:
Installato: (nessuno)
Candidato:  (nessuno)
Tabella versione:
libgtkglext1:
Installato: (nessuno)
Candidato:  (nessuno)
Tabella versione:
```

I also tried to install such dependencies, but one more time something else goes wrong and this issue goes in a complicated thread of errors which makes me lost.

Anyone who can help me finding the right path to deal with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable universe repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Or you can manually edit your sources.list:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
```

then:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com ulyssa main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main

deb https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu  focal main restricted  universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run `sudo apt update`

Installation guide: [AnyDesk DEB repository how-to](http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html)

Comment: Very Helpful, i was not able to install AnyDesk in ubuntu 20, tried the first option.

Comment: @Brucewayne-TheGeekKiller Welcome, could you ask a new question, please explain what you have tried.